# Getting Text From Flash

Tags: c#, webresponse

I have a problem usint httpWebRequest httpWebResponse. The problem is am trying to fetch data from a website which contains loads of text regarding some documents and articles which are inside the flash. How can i get the text inside the flash? The httpWebResponse does not contain the full text present in the page?

Answer (score 0):

If what you get with your request is the HTML page containing the flash app then no, you won't get any of the text inside the flash app.

If what you get with your request is the flash file (swf), then you may try to parse the flash file to extract all strings from it, however it may not be what you are looking for as reading a flash file is not trivial, and the text you will get will most likely be divided in different randomly ordered pieces, mixed up with unsignificant technical data.
.NET does not natively read flash files so you'll have to find some library (I'm not aware of any existing project doing that kind of stuff) or do the decompiling by yourself.